# WinAPI - C++ - Add Hyperlink to Window

Tags: c++, winapi

I was wondering, how can I add a hyperlink (A link to an online webpage) to my window. Do I use CreateWindow, WM_PAINT, etc? Please give me some advice. Thanks!

**Edit:**
Here's what i'm doing:

```
HWND CreateSysLink(HWND hDlg, HINSTANCE hInst, RECT rect){
    return CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LINK,
                          "For more information, <A HREF=\"http://www.microsoft.com\">click here</A> " \
                          "or <A ID=\"idInfo\">here</A>.",
                          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP,
                          rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom,
                          hDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
}
```

I'm copying the hInstance from WinMain parameters to a global variable "globalhInstance" by running **globalhInstance = hInstance;** in WinMain. I'm also creating a global RECT called globalRect. Then on WM_CREATE, I'm calling **GetWindowRect(hwnd, &globalRect);** ("hwnd" is a parameter of WndProc). Finally, in a switch statement inside WM_COMMAND i'm calling **CreateSysLink(hwnd, globalhInstance, globalRect);**. But it just doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Are you looking for the [SysLink common control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760706(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: [`CreateWindowEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680.aspx)`( 0x0, `[`WC_LINK`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775491.aspx#WC_LINK)`, ... );`

Comment: Could you give me some sample code

Comment: If it's a dialog box and you have Visual C++ then you can drag & drop "SysLink control" from Toolbox.

Comment: @JonathanPotter - No i'm just putting **RECT globalRect;** below my includes at the top of my .cpp file and calling **GetWindowRect(hwnd, &globalRect);** on WM_CREATE.

Comment: You need to provide valid coordinates that tell Windows where the control is positioned and how big it is. Have you ever actually created a window before?

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh.... I thought it wanted a Rect of the window. Im so dumb :p Sorry, i'm really tired. And yes - i've created a window before. Thanks!

Comment: @jadenPete: `CreateWindowEx` does want a `RECT` specifying the size of the control to be created. Since this is a child window, you will have to pass **client coordinates**. [`GetWindowRect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633519.aspx) returns **screen coordinates**.

Answer (score 4):

There's [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298379(v=vs.85).aspx) from the MSDN page linked above:

```
HWND CreateSysLink(HWND hDlg, HINSTANCE hInst, RECT rect)
{
    return CreateWindowExW(0, WC_LINK, 
        L"For more information, <A HREF=\"http://www.microsoft.com\">click here</A> " \
        L"or <A ID=\"idInfo\">here</A>.", 
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_TABSTOP, 
        rect.left, rect.top, rect.right, rect.bottom, 
        hDlg, NULL, hInst, NULL);
}
```

Comment: I know but my compiler says: error: cannot convert 'const wchar_t*' to 'LPCSTR {aka const char*}' for argument '3' to 'HWND__* CreateWindowExA(DWORD, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, DWORD, int, int, int, int, HWND, HMENU, HINSTANCE, LPVOID)' btw, im using GNU GCC compiler

Comment: That code is calling the `TCHAR` version of `CreateWindowEx()`, so wrap string literals with the `TEXT()` macro, eg: `return CreateWindowEx(0, WC_LINK, TEXT("For more information, ..."), ...);`.  Otherwise, call `CreateWindowExW()` directly instead (the `WC_LINK` class does not support `CreateWindowExA()`) passing it wide string literals (prefixed with `L`), eg: `return CreateWindowExW(0, WC_LINK, L"For more information, ...", ...);`.

Comment: I hate to complain, but wrapping them with Text() compiled fine, but the link wont show. Using CreateWindowExW and L"" shows the same error

Comment: @jadenPete This is basic Win32 stuff, creating child windows. Without seeing more of your code we have no idea what could be going wrong. E.g. are you passing valid coordinates?

Comment: @jadenPete Before creating SysLink controls, you must call the InitCommonControlsEx function, specifying the ICC_LINK_CLASS. [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/create-syslink-controls?redirectedfrom=MSDN)